# What is wrong with this Excel Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula `=IF(G6="", "", CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT(G6),"]","Sheet1","!$A1"))`.

It is reading excel `file name` from column `G6`, and then it read `Column A` from `Sheet1`.

This give invalid `Cell Reference Error`. Is there is something wrong with this?

Comment: try this:

=IF(G6="", "", CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT("G6"),"]",Sheet1!$A1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
=IF(G6="", "", INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[",G6,"]Sheet1'!$A1")))
```

If `G6` holds the text `zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx`, then the formula is equivalent to

```
='[zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A1
```

which will yield the value of cell `A1` of `Sheet1` of file `zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx`…

Comment: Oh Thank god, finally it is working, You are too good man. Unfortunately i can only upvote once :(
Ok now little imprvement, when i drag that formula to other cells it changes `G6` to `G7, G8` and onwards, i do not want that. `G6` needs to be fixed in formula only `$A` needs to be changed for each cell. Please help

Comment: Then please [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Note: it is the dollar-sign `$` that fixes a reference row or column: in `A1` no row/column is fixed, in `$A1` the column is fixed, in `A$1` the row is fixed, in `$A$1` both row and column are fixed; same rules apply to your `G6` :]

Comment: This is what I answered long time ago!

Comment: @Eder: yes, now I see, but you forgot the opening apostrophe. And if the referenced file is not password protected, there actually is no need to have it open: one can simply include the full directory path between the opening apostrophe and the opening bracket similar to this: `CONCATENATE("'C:\My share\[",G6,"]Sheet1'!$A1")` or just use another reference for it.

Comment: @mousio, yes I forgot the opening apostrophe +1 for making it clear!

Comment: @mousio how can i increase cell reference in `INDIRECT` e.g. in `INDIRECT($G$6&"!$X1")` i want to update `X1` to `X2` and so on. But `X1` is in double quotes so `$` don't work to fix column. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please see my answer for [using relative positions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5603822/653295) and play around with the various alternatives to find what suits you best :]

Comment: Use `INDIRECT($G$6&"!RC", false)` instead of `INDIRECT($G$6&"!$X1")`; use `R<number>` (e.g. `R5`) for an absolute value, or use `R[<number>]` (e.g. `R[-2]`) for a relative value: note the brackets; same goes for `C`… Or you can use a construct like `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(…))` but it all depends on your specific needs. [BTW, it seems I was mistaken about the referenced file not needing to be open; sorry]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(G6="", "", CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT("G6"),"]",Sheet1!$A1))
```

You missed a double quote around G6

Comment: If i add double quote it does not evaluate the concatenated string, it just print the the concatenated string in cell. How to solve that?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry I missed that.  Checking that part.

Comment: A hint is that =CONCATENATE("a","b",INDIRECT("G6")) is working perfectly fine, so the issue is with "!$A1".  Let's try something else.

Comment: I guess this should work.

=IF(G6="", "", CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT("G6"),"]",Sheet1!$A1))

Comment: When i enter the formula it opens the File Dialouge Box to choose file. Does it supposed to that? And when i choose file it just print the concatenated string again in cell

Comment: Really?  It did not do that for me, it simply printed the value in G6 column and A1 column.

Comment: Ok it is now printing the value, But strange that when i enter formula it open file dialogue box to choose file, and when i choose file it print this `[zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx]4636181` it just supposed to print only `4636181`, why it is printing file name? and why i supposed to choose file? i dont want that, as i have thousand of lines to render, Please help :(

Comment: i think `[zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx]` this in a cell value causing it to open file dialouge box, if we some how find a solution that only `4636181` is printed then problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past,

First you need to have the excel file that you are reading/searching for, open. Then you have to use `INDIRECT` after `CONCATENATE`:

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[", G6, "]", "Sheet1","'!$A1"))
```

**NOTE**

You are forgetting `'` before `!` in `"!$A1"` should be `"'!$A1"`

Comment: @SidCool, my bad I forgot to mention that you don't need the full path on G6 only the name of the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
=IF(G6=""; ""; CONCATENATE("[";INDIRECT("G6");"]";Sheet1!$A1))
```

My Excel tells me I should use semicolons (;) in functions (althogh I do not have english version). Also you should not divide Sheet1 and address - they will only work when used together: Sheet1!$A1. This should also not be wrapped in "".

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, I am getting error.

This worked for me, though:

=IF(G6="", "", CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT("G6"),"]",Sheet1!$A1))

Comment: When i enter the formula it opens the File Dialouge Box to choose file. Does it supposed to that? And when i choose file it just print the concatenated string again in cell

Comment: What ever is inside `CONCATENATE` it also get printed with value so i got this in the end `[zipcodes-phoenixTEST.xlsx]4636181`. Which is causing the file dialouge to open. But the result should need to be only `4636181`. I tried to wrap the whole `CONCATENATE` with `INDIRECT` as `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",INDIRECT("G6"),"]",Sheet1!$A1))` But this does not even work. Desperately need the solution

Comment: @SidCool the semicolons are probably specific to my language version.

Comment: @AamirAdnan no, it should not bring file open dialog. It should take the value of G6 cell and concatenate it with square brackets and value from $A1 cell from Sheet1.